# ActiveMQ -- Messages not being delivered until the Broker is restarted

Tags: activemq-classic, message, restart, broker

I am using ActiveMQ v5.6. It has one consumer. It works fine in most of the cases. But sometimes, messages wont be dispatched and they accumulate in the queue. BUT, once I restart the Broker, it works fine again. I searched to see if anyone else was facing the same problem and found a number of sites where the issue has been reported. For example,

http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Stuck-messages-Dispatch-issues-td2367852i20.html

But all these posts are way back in 2008. Has this issue been fixed? Is anyone else facing the same problem?

Comment: Need more details here, what're the consumers doing? How have you coded them. What are the inflight, enqueue, dequeue count at the time of the issue.

Comment: I have only one producer and one consumer configured. And I am not able to reproduce this. It occurs very randomly. Plus, it occurs in the test environment only and never in the development environment. I will collect these details the next time the issue occurs. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its related to flow control kicking in

- http://activemq.apache.org/what-happens-with-a-fast-producer-and-slow-consumer.html
- http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html

Comment: Thank you for the links. But in my application, there is only one producer and one consumer. And plus, if it was a fast producer and a slow consumer, then it should result in an OutOfMemoryException, right. That is not happening. So, I am not sure if this is the reason. Is there any other reason why this is occurring?